# Determine origin of a check constraint in Oracle

Tags: oracle, constraints

I received an oracle check constraint error when I attempt to complete an action from an application that updates an oracle database.
The error is this:

> ORA-02290: check constraint (.SYS_C00357711) violated must
>   be Y or N

I look up the check constraint in the all_constraint table using the name, SYS_C00357711. The search condition in the table is:  **cannot be null.**

There are 2 issues that I don't understand.  First the column values are not N/Y but a 3 or 4 character string. Second, the record that my query returns does not have this column as null.  The value is consistent with the other records.

Am I not looking at the correct constraint?
Where is the text that creates the error message (..violated must be N or Y) get set?  It is clearly not the search condition field in the constraint table.

Comment: sorry...that was a typo.  The constraint query I ran was: select constraint_name,search_condition, table_name 
from all_constraints
where CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'SYS_C00357711';

Comment: My suspicion is that the 'must be Y or N' text is being added incorrectly by your application.  The ORA-02290 error message normally ends with the word 'violated'.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that developer (who wrote that application) caused confusion.

Here's how Oracle normally handles such a check constraint violation:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (col varchar2(1) check (col in ('Y', 'N')));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (col) values ('X');
insert into test (col) values ('X')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C007013) violated


SQL>
```

As you can see, no additional "must be Y or N" message.

I suspect that the application does the following: first, find constraint name:

```
SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_C007013

SQL>
```

Now use it: declare an exception (`ex_chk` in my example) and pragma `exception_init` which says that `ex_chk` should be used for `ORA-02290`. So, if check constraint is violated, display a message which *looks like* the original one and add some more info:

```
SQL> declare
  2    ex_chk    exception;
  3    pragma    exception_init(ex_chk, -2290);
  4  begin
  5    insert into test (col) values ('x');
  6  exception
  7    when ex_chk then
  8      dbms_output.put_line
  9        ('ORA-02290: check constraint (.SYS_C007013) violated must be Y or N');
 10  end;
 11  /
ORA-02290: check constraint (.SYS_C007013) violated must be Y or N

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I guess you don't do that in SQL*Plus, but any application (for example, Oracle Forms) is capable of doing that, maybe not using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` call but `MESSAGE`, `ALERT` or whatever else.

Therefore, check the application itself. You won't find that info within the database, unless such a PL/SQL code is *stored* as a procedure - standalone or within a pacakge. In that case:

```
select * from user_source where upper(text) like '%SYS_C007013%';
```

Comment: I suspect you're right, but it might be more likely that it is using a modified `SQLERRM` in the generated message/exception, to remove/hide the schema name; rather than having the constraint name hard-coded - particularly for a system-generated name?

Comment: I agree, @Alex - what I wrote was what I suspect. I didn't feel like adding additional *clutter* by finding constraint name out of USER_CONSTRAINTS. If my *idea* is what it really is, the OP will find real code anyway. It would be interesting to see how it looks like.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think they'll find it by searching the code for the constraint name. (I was thinking it's doing `replace(sqlerrm, user, null) || ' must be...'` not looking up the name though.)

Comment: True; I should have written `like '%Y OR N%'` or something like that, but - if it is not a stored procedure, that query won't help anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. This application actually has THREE PL/SQL layers and it is probably in one of the those.  Will look into it.  Thanks again for the info.  Would have NEVER thought someone would actually do that.

Comment: I was pulled off this problem to troubleshoot another problem.  but will come back to this a the near future.